# Using jQuery to update content within an iFrame live & on-the-fly...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, keyup

I'm using an iframe to display a website next to a form. I want to update certain content within that iframe live based upon the value of the various input fields.

This is what I'm trying to do (working outside of an iframe): http://jsfiddle.net/YkKUS/

The textarea will be outside of the iframe and the content that'll be updated will be inside the iframe.

Here is my code adapted to work with my iframe:

```
            $('.liveDemoFrame').load( function(){   // load the iframe          
                $(this.contentDocument).find('h1').html($('textarea').val());                   
                $('textarea').keyup(function() {
                    $(this.contentDocument).find('h1').html($(this).val()); // this line is screwing something up?!?
                });    
            });
```

The 5th line is causing me some problems. The iframe DOES actually update successfully with the content of my textarea but only when I refresh the page. It's not updating it live & on-the-fly which is the only reason I'm doing this!

Thanks!

Comment: Ah now I saw, if only you would have put your full code in jsfiddle. this in your keyup function refers to the textarea dom element, not the iframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in the parent page and it seemed to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textarea').bind('keyup', function() {
        var iframedoc = $('#iframe').get(0).contentDocument;
        $(iframedoc).find('h1').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some kinks with jQuery, or you might be doing it incorrectly. Either way, it could be easiest to actually run half of your code *within* the iframe; then you can call iframe.contentWindow.getHtml(), or iframe.contentWindow.setHtml(), if you can. Also IIRC, the contentDocument was not standard either; some browsers require contentWindow.document or similar.

However, the main culprit would be this:

```
$('.liveDemoFrame').load( function(){
    $(this.contentDocument).find('h1').html($('textarea').val());
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
         // here this refers to textarea dom element, not iframe
         $(this.contentDocument).find('h1').html($(this).val()); 
    });    
});
```

Fix could be like

```
$('.liveDemoFrame').load( function(){
    var iframeDocument = $(this.contentDocument);
    iframeDocument.find('h1').html($('textarea').val());
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
         // here this refers to textarea dom element, not iframe
         iframeDocument.find('h1').html($(this).val()); 
    });    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do stuff in the iframe from outside of it, that would be a massive security hole

Comment: Really? I can use stuff like hide() on specific areas within the iframe which works fine but the keyup event doesn't work at all.

Comment: hmm, is the iframe the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: yeah it is. I read somewhere that having jquery included within the iframe page as well could cause an issue so I tried removing it and still no luck.

Comment: Also - the value of the textarea IS successfully changing the t1Title class. It's just not working live as you type in the text area as it should be.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a different domain... I mean.. why else would you use an iframe right?? ;) Anyway let me have a fiddle...

Comment: haha, it's for my site generator script. I'm building a "live demo" type preview thing so as you run through the generator form, it updates the live demo on the fly. iFrame felt like the easiest option.